# How to make sharp textures in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a plain image data (32 bit RGBA) of `size` in a char array and want to make a **cocos2d-x** Texture2D out of it as in:

```
Texture2D * tex = new Texture2D();
tex->initWithData(data, 4*size.width*size.height, Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888,size.width, size.height, size);
tex->drawAtPoint(Point(offset));
```

but the resulting image is blurry (like a compressed jpeg image)..
Both the input and texture (as seen above) have size `size` and I am not making any transformations. I just put the code in `HelloWorld::draw(Renderer *, const kmMat4&, bool)` in a newly created project. How can I get a sharp image (the exact representation of data)? Any other suggestions (like a direct frame-buffer like thing ...etc if any exist) are also welcome.

I am using v3.0 in mac os 10.8.x

Edit: I tried setting Texture params (GL_NEAREST) just after `Texture2D` creation and before `initWithData` and nothing changed. Data and texture are the same size so it should not do resizing anyway... Here is a picture; corners of the rectangles are not sharp:

[image]

Edit2: setting texture parameters (GL_NEAREST) **after** `initWithData` worked:

...

```
Texture2D::TexParams tp = {GL_NEAREST, GL_NEAREST, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE};
tex->setTexParameters(tp);
tex->drawAtPoint(Point(offset));
```

Comment: Could you include a screenshot? When I think of compressed jpeg images, I think of compression artifacts, not so much blurriness. You seem to be describing two contradictory things and I think what you actually want is point sampling (`GL_NEAREST`) min/mag filter.

Comment: @see Edit. (Thanks, by the way)

Comment: Honestly, assuming that image was not rescaled in an image editing program, it still looks like it is using linear interpolation to me. *(I edited your question to display the image larger to show the actual smoothing going on.)* Are those rectangles part of your texture? The other possibility is that you are rescaling your famebuffer itself - the color buffer can be linearly interpolated during blitting from an FBO to the default framebuffer and it would produce this sort of result.

Comment: @see Edit2: I will accept it if you write as an answer. I want to ask a few more (opengl) questions, but will ask them as separate questions after (hopefully enough) googling... Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description of the problem, I have to assume that the GL texture associated with a `Texture2D` object is not actually created until you call `Texture2D::initWithData (...)`.

In OpenGL, the default texture magnification filter is `GL_LINEAR`. You *do not* want the default mag filter in this case, but you also cannot change the filter until ***after*** you initialize your texture. Setting a `GL_NEAREST` mag filter after the texture is created will eliminate the smoothing when you upscale the texture.

Comment: I did not request (and see) any scaling/resize for the texture but probably (and unfortunately) the framework (cocos) is doing it internally...

Comment: By scaling, I am actually referring to when the texture is sampled. If the texture-mapped rectangle does not have the same dimensions on screen as the texture then scaling inevitably occurs. The magnification filter is used when the source texture is smaller than the covered size on screen. `GL_NEAREST` makes it so that instead of finding the 4 nearest texels and smoothing them, it just outputs the single nearest texel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> usually the game needs to keep the look of the pixel images sharp /
>   none blurred

http://www.gamedevcraft.com/2015/10/disable-texture-anti-aliasing.html